# "404 Not Found" while importing ng-chartist in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am having issue while working on ng-chartist. I installed everything as documented here: https://pixinvent.com/apex-angular-4-bootstrap-admin-template/documentation/documentation-charts-chartist.html

As I import ChartistModule from ng-chartist, I get error:

```
Error: Fetch error: 404 Not Found
  Instantiating http://localhost:37337/ng-chartist
```

I have tried to give exact path of ng-chartist as well but it does not work.
I have tried to load chart as:

```
import * as Chartist from 'chartist';
```

but while creating an instance of the chart:

```
            new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
                labels: myLabels,
                series: myseriesData
            }, {
                    low: 0,
                    showArea: true,
                    showPoint: true,
                    width: 400,
                    height: 400,
                    fullWidth: true,
                });
```

I get the same error.

Comment: When posting code/logs here, please use the code formatting tool. It's in the toolbar, and well worth learning before your next question. This will reduce the amount of editing that volunteers need to undertake to repair the post.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I posted the question first time on Stackoverflow and was not aware of such issues...will be careful next time...

Comment: If you want to implement chart you can use ng2-charts

Answer (score 0):

You should install ng-chartist using these commands

`npm i ng-chartist`

`npm install chartist --save`

`npm install @types/chartist --save-dev`

or

`yarn add ng-chartist`

`yarn add chartist --save`

`yarn add @types/chartist --save-dev`